# Div's Auto Dimensionaveís

Tags: jquery, html5, css3, jquery-ui

Estou com uma dúvida, estou criando uma página [html](/questions/tagged/html) onde irei ter **3 colunas**, porém o **usuário ira redimensionar** ela da forma que quiser, entretanto **automaticamente** as `divs` terão que se **auto ajustar**!

Estou usando a propriedade `resizable` do **jqueryUI**.

Gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar

```css
#container {
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}

#left {
 float:left;
 width:32%;
 height: 20px;
 background: #000;
}

#center {
 display: inline-block;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:32%;
 height: 20px;
 background: #00ff00;
}

#right {
 float:right;
 width:32%;
 height: 20px;
 background: #7b8787;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="center"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Quando esticar qualquer uma das `divs` para qualquer lado elas devem se ajustar automaticamente.

Comment: Coloque o código que vc já tem ai pra gente ver como vc está fazendo, e entender melhor o que está acontecendo

Comment: Teria algum problema de fazer isso com colunas de uma tabela?

Comment: Você quer que as colunas internas tenham resize de largura e quando o usuário estiver fazendo o resize as outras colunas devem se ajustar conforme o layout ou permanecer do mesmo tamanho criando um scroll horizontal?

Comment: Exemplo se o usuário quiser expandir a coluna central mais para esquerda ou para direita ele pode porem as 2Div's tem que se ajustarem para não ficar nenhum espaço em branco.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo com 3 colunas, veja se ajuda Exemplo:jsfiddle.net/afcv0vem/

Comment: Valew !
Isso mesmo só que é para os dois lados ..!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar as propriedades do flexbox para isso, basta transformar seu container em um flex container, e depois ajustar seus elementos filhos com a propriedade flex, que faz com o "conteudo preencha automagicamente o espaço restante no container"

Exemplo a partir do seu código:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
    width:32%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
  flex: 1;
}

#center {
    width:32%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #00ff00;
  flex: 1;
}

#right {
    width:32%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #7b8787;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Para saber mais sobre flexbox, da uma olhada nesse projeto:

https://github.com/afonsopacifer/awesome-flexbox

:)